# Monospace System Font

Tags: font

Is it possible at all to change my system font (Big Sur) so that file names of the same length are actually the same length regardless of their text content?

I think what I want is a monospaced font, but there may be a better word?

Here is an image of what I'd like to resolve illustrated with files that are all named the same length, but with different dates. I guess to my eye, it just looks ugly!

[image: mis-aligned filenames]

What is this default font? It's really infuriating! .

Comment: It’s awful… the number of times I had an I/l/1 and rn/m confusion with the standard font are aggravating. TIL that there seems to be no way to make things legible… there’s even a DIN standard that this is violating…

Comment: winds me up to this day :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple does not readily provide mechanisms for customizing the system fonts. MacOS uses a font called San Francisco, specifically designed by Apple for the user interface.

You can however use the Terminal, which uses a mono-spaced font, to list a directory's contents, when you want to see things lined up.

Comment: urgh, thanks for the clarification - it is quite grating to my eyes 